# Запуск / перезапуск таймера при определенных условиях

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать такое поведение, чтобы когда вводится новая буква в поле, проходила 1 секунда и выполнялся определенный метод. Для этого нужен таймер, но когда идет быстрый ввод букв (например 3 буквы в секунду), то таймеры становятся в очередь и потом последовательно выполняются.

Требуется, чтобы был таймер который при каждой новой введенной букве будет запускаться заново, но если буквы не вводились в течении 1 сек. тогда запускался нужный метод.

Вот мой код:

```
var isTimerWork = false;
        var timer = null;

$('#SearchString').on("keyup", function() {
                if ($('#SearchString').val().length >= 2 && !IsExtSearch) {
                    if (timer != null)
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(isTimerWork = true, 1000);
                    while (!isTimerWork);
                    GetAutoCompleteData($('#SearchString').val());
                }
```

в моем случае получается, что создается новый таймер каждый раз.

Comment: в твоем случае ты мог висеть бесконечно в цикле while `(!isTimerWork);` если б сразу перед ним не присвоил этой переменной `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте более правильно функцию setInterval,

```
setTimeout(function() { 
//тут код, который выполнится через 1 секунду
}, 1000);
```

Исправленный Ваш пример:

```js
var timer = null;

$('#SearchString').on("keyup",
  function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    if ($('#SearchString').val().length >= 2) {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($('#SearchString').val());
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="SearchString" type="text" name="test" value="a" />
```

Comment: на null можно не проверять. И раз _clearTimeout_ вызывается в обоих ветвях - можно вынести этот вызов из условия

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, поправил

Comment: `if` тоже можно убрать и сразу clearTimeout вызывать